# Check if current_user is the owner of a resource and allow edit/delete actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

**Example:**

User **A** (id=10) has created a **photo** resource

```
photo: (id: 1 user_id = 10, url: "http://...")
```

Now, if User **B** (id=20) go to this url: `/photos/1/edit` it can edit photo of user **A**!!!

**Rails+Devise** provides something for this by default? It seems it's a very common issue

I just need to allow that any user can edit/delete ONLY resource it has created (where current_user == resource.user)

**Using:** Rails 4, Devise

**Update:**

I think CanCan it's something too advanced. I don't need roles or restrict some actions to certain users

Comment: Have a look at CanCan https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: cancan isn't very well maintained anymore. Last commit 2 months ago. 189 open issues. It's also a pretty bloated tool for simple authorization. Personally, I prefer https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: @Deefour thx for pointing this out, pundit looks great

Comment: A continuation gem of cancan is actively maintened, [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to anyone interesed

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your PhotosController:

```
before_filter :require_permission, only: :edit

def require_permission
  if current_user != Photo.find(params[:id]).user
    redirect_to root_path
    #Or do something else here
  end
end
```

Comment: You will need to handle ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception here.

Comment: @NiravGandhi AFAIK, only the `!` versions of the ActiveRecord methods will throw that exception. Otherwise, the result will just be `nil`, which of course should also be handled.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice On Rails `4.2.8` and ActiveRecord `2.5.1`, there is no `find!` - `find` itself will definitely throw an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.

Comment: Wouldn't this make you fetch the record again in the controller action method again?

Answer (score 17):

You can make use of Rails' associations and write it like this:

```
def edit
  @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])

  # ... do everything else
end
```

This will only find a record when the photo with the supplied ID belongs to the current user. If it doesn't, Rails will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception.

Of course, I'm assuming the `current_user` method is available and your `User` model contains the statement `has_many :photos`.

Comment: This is the most elegant solution for this simple problem. +1

Answer (score 3):

Check this railscasts,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

Complications you will run into,

1. When you want cancan authorization on User Model that Devise gem is using for authentication
2. When you want to store your Roles in the Database
3. When you want to assign Permissions to the Roles as an Admin from the webUI
4. and more ..

Please comment if you want any of those features, I will be happy to help, because I recently did them with great help from others and its always amazing to pass it on.

A sample Ability for your resources can be like as follows,

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

      user ||= User.new # guest users
      send(user.role.name)

        if user.role.blank?
          can :read, User #for guest without roles
        end

  end

  def man
    can :manage, Photo
  end


  def boy
    can :read, Photo
  end

  def kid
    can :read, Article
  end

end
```

Comment: 1) User model is used my Devise. Just this

Comment: You want to know how to do it?

Comment: I was thinking that I need something very simpler. I just need to allow that any user can edit/delete ONLY resource it has created (where current_user == resource.user). Cancan is something more advanced

Answer (score 2):

I captured the exception from within a before_filter action:

```
before_action :set_photo, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def set_photo
  @photo = current_user.photos.find(params[:id])

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to(root_url, :notice => 'Record not found')
end
```

Hope this helps someone. I'm using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.

Answer (score 1):

So you are using `gem devise`.

This gem provides the `current_user` for the currently logged in user.

In your `PhotosController#edit` method. I'd do something like below.

```
def edit
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thou Shalt Nought duuu dat :(' unless current_user.id == @photo.user_id
  ...
end
```

This method is cheaper because you already have 2 objects to compare instead of running a query in the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to to modify routes.rb.

Assign photos to live in the current_user path.

For example,

```
devise_for :users

resources 'users' do 
  resources 'photos'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

cancan is difficult and complicate
i have coding `is_onwer` method
it's very simple, easy

https://gist.github.com/x1wins/0d3f0058270cef37b2d3f25a56a3745d

> application controller

```
 def is_owner user_id
    unless user_id == current_user.id
      render json: nil, status: :forbidden
      return
    end
  end
  def is_owner_object data
    if data.nil? or data.user_id.nil?
      return render status: :not_found
    else
      is_owner data.user_id
    end
  end
```

> your controller

```
  before_action only: [:edit, :update, :destroy] do
    is_owner_object @article ##your object
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Write another before_filter in application_controller:

```
before_filter :has_permission?

has_permission?
controllers=["articles", "photos", "..."]
actions=["edit", "destroy", "..."]
id = params[:id] if (controllers.include?(params[:controller] && actions.include?(params[:action]) end
if id && (current_user.id==(params[:controller][0...1].capitalize!+params[:controller].singularize[1...-1] + ".find(#{id}).user_id").send)
return true
else
redirect_to root_url, :notice=>"no permission for this action"
end

helper_method :has_permission?
```

And you can use it in views, not to show users link they can't follow.

Some kind of this, of course you need to modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: This is a bad idea. There are too many tested, more flexible, more readable, well written gems to handle authorization. There is no need to reinvent the wheel with something fragile like this.

Comment: @Deefour, it is just example. For some reasons there is sense in not using gems where you can avoid it. Best approach is model without DB table, but whole issue tutorial suits more for article, than for answer.

Comment: This idea seems interesting. @Deefour which are gems for doing something like this? (CanCan is too advanced for this problem)

Comment: @user1028100 as I mentioned in the Question's comments, I use **[pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)**.

Answer (score 0):

If CanCan is too advanced, you should loon into checking the id of the accessor in the controller using...

```
if @user.id == @photo.user_id
  # edit photo details
else
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "You! Shall! Not! Edit!"
```

...or something like that