# Only allow owner of article to delete it using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently completed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and added a [user authentication system](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch-revised), so only a registered user can create / delete a blog post / article.  However, presently any user can delete any article.  I would like to restrict access to the delete / destroy action of an article to the owner of the article, i.e. only the owner of an article can delete it.

**Update** my code files look like the following,

**Articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def destroy
            @article = Article.find_by_slug(params[:id])
            if current_user == @article.user
                @article.destroy
            end

            redirect_to articles_path
    end
```

**Article.rb**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

# user singluar form of model when using 'belongs_to'
# see this SO thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257116
belongs_to :user
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :articles
```

and the migration file, **AddUserIdToArticles.rb**

```
class AddUserIdToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :user_id, :integer
    add_column :users, :user_id, :integer
    add_foreign_key :articles, :users
  end
end
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?  You have authentication, now you need the other part (Authorization) The railscast on can can is a bit outdate in regards to rails4.x  but you can look at something like the `pundit gem`

Comment: Or just use a before_destroy callback?

Comment: I was looking into something like this => http://stackoverflow.com/a/17793864/708807

Comment: Take a look at CanCan https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: @Chris for one off, yes you can a before_action filter, or you can just scope the object lookup to current_user, so it will only find ones they own, etc...  lots of ways to do this.

Comment: If you wanna do a complete Authentication & Authorization part for your Web site, the have a look at Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book, https://www.railstutorial.org/book, most of the chapters 6 to 9 cover what you need. In that solution current_user method is also used.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a helper function `current_user`, you can do the following in your articlesController :

```
def destroy
    @article=Article.find(params[:id])
    if current_user == @article.user
        @article.destroy
    end
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

Now the destroy action will be executed only if the `current_user` who is signed in is the actual writer of the post

Comment: I have a `current_user` instance variable setup in the application_controller.rb but when I try to delete a post it is giving me the following error, undefined method user for #<Article:0x00000006b08ff0>  I think I am missing the relationship in the models from `User` model to `Article` model.

Comment: Yes you need a has_many and belongs_to accordingly to be able to reference @article.user

Comment: Don't forget to use the same if statement to hide the link "delete" in the view

Comment: I added the `has_many` and `belongs_to` to the models, but I am still not able to delete articles, I'm getting the following in the dev log, Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

Comment: Did you generate a migration to add the foreign key to the articles table ?

Comment: did not I guess I'll have to do that later, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a authorization gem such as [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for that in most cases; these allow you to explicitly set authorization like you described. It would also be possible for really simple situations to just write your own, e.g.

```
private

def set_article 
  @article = current_user.articles
end
```

Then set create a before filter `before_filter :set_article, only: [:index, :show]`

The only part is optional and could be omitted for the filter to apply to all methods in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
# user model
has_many :articles


# controller
def destroy
  current_user.articles.find(params[id]).destroy
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

The code will also raise 404 if the current_user is not the owner of the article